# In WinRT, how to Reflect for Properties that implement an Interface?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime

Sometimes, in the Windows Runtime you want to return a list of class properties that implement a certain interface. Unfortunately, some of the .Net helper methods that made this possible are missing or moved. How do you Reflect for Properties that implement a certain Interface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
using System.Reflection;

/// <summary>Finds properties that implement a type</summary>
/// <param name="parent">The parent type</param>
/// <param name="type">The filter type</param>
/// <returns>Enumerable of PropertyInfo</returns>
IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> Properties(Type parent, Type type)
{
    var typeinfo = type.GetTypeInfo();
    var properties = parent.GetRuntimeProperties();
    foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
    {
        var propertytypeinfo = property.PropertyType.GetTypeInfo();
        if (typeinfo.IsAssignableFrom(propertytypeinfo))
            yield return property;
    }
}
```

Best of luck!